# MS Teams Bot framework > Need to whitelist smba.trafficmanager.net?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am whitelisting some of the urls on my corporate firewall for a botframework app. The urls to be whitelisted are provided in [this link](http://login.botframework.com%20(Bot%20authentication)%20login.microsoftonline.com%20(Bot%20authentication)%20westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com%20(for%20Luis.ai%20NLP%20integration)%20*.botframework.com%20(channels)).
But when I tracked the outgoing traffic from my local development, I saw that url (`smba.trafficmanager.net`) was also being used which is not listed in the whitelist urls provided in [microsoft documentation website](http://login.botframework.com%20(Bot%20authentication)%20login.microsoftonline.com%20(Bot%20authentication)%20westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com%20(for%20Luis.ai%20NLP%20integration)%20*.botframework.com%20(channels)). Do I need to whitelist this?

Since this is the ServiceUrl for conversation between user and the bot and is supposed to change in time, do the whole url (including domain, subdomain, port) changes or just the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need that one as well for proactive messaging, but the base url should be fine - it's just the paths that change (e.g. https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/ or https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/ or https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/).